# Atualizar um TableView

Tags: c++, qt

Como posso atualizar um TableView, depois de fechar um Dialog?

Exemplo:
principal.ccp  `abre conexão com banco de dados`

```
principal::principal(){
//..etc..//
model->setTable("nomeTabela");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Lista da tabela"));
model->select();
}
```

Dialog.cpp  `Apenas query de insert na tabela nomeTabela`

```
void Dialog::on_cadastroDados_clicked()
{
   QSqlQuery qry;
   qry.prepare("INSERT INTO nomeTabela/..
   qry.addBindValue/...
   qry.exec/..
   //true
   QDialog::Closet();            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode executar um `setModel()` novamente para o `TableView`, logo após fechar o `Dialog`:

```
// ...
model->select();
ui->tableView1->setModel(model);
```

Assumindo que o nome do seu `TableView` seja `tableView1`.

---

Você chama isso após o usuário fechar o diálogo, por exemplo:

```
DialogoExemplo dlg(this);

// Mostra o dialogo e espera o usuário retornar ou cancelar a janela.
if( dlg.exec() == QDialog::Accepted )
{
    // O usuário fechou o dialogo corretamente (não cancelou).
    // Pare o caso dlg ser fechado usando QDialog::accept().
    model->select();
    ui->tableView1->setModel(model);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Você fala logo após fechar Dialog. Na onde seria ?

Comment: @user628298 Adicionei um exemplo a resposta.

Comment: Voltou um `error: cannot call member function 'bool QWidget::close()' without object
             if(dcl->exec() == QDialog::close())
                                              ^`

Comment: Use o `this->accept()` (na clase do dialogo) para fechar. E use `QDialog::Accepted` no `if`. Se você tratar apenas o caso de fechar, você vai aceitar quando o usuário abrir o diálogo e fechar sem fazer nenhuma alteração.

Comment: Funcionou, Muito obrigado.